# How to call code that is a private inner class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

How to touch the inner class code starting with the

`for (Additional_Contact_Role__c cr : contactsFromQ_List2)` statement below in a test class?

```
// Inner class
    public class selectedPerson{
        public boolean isSelected {get;set;}
        //public Contact contact {get;set;}
        public Additional_Contact_Role__c contactR {get;set;}
    }

    public list<selectedPerson> selectedContacts_List {get;set;}
    public list<selectedPerson> completeContacts4VF_List {get;set;}

    private Training_Resource__c currentQ = new Training_Resource();

        selectedContacts_List = new list<selectedPerson>();
        selectedPerson sp = new selectedPerson();
        completeContacts4VF_List = new list<selectedPerson>();

        for (Additional_Contact_Role__c cr : contactsFromQ_List2){
// Starting here  ---> sp = new selectedPerson();
            sp.isSelected = true;
            sp.contactR = cr;
            completeContacts4VF_List.add(sp);
        }
```

Comment: It is not understandable. Could you please describe it more, what you want to do.

Comment: Syntax to call inner class is: `MainClassName.InnerClassname obj= new MainClassName.InnerClassname();`

Comment: It's a private method. It cannot be called from anywhere except the class it's declared in. Not even the "parent" class can call it, being private.

Comment: You're object structure is confusing, do you have a json that your trying to mock? or api your trying to hit

Answer (score 4):

You can add `@testVisible` to your private inner class if you want to be able to directly access it in a Test Method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any coverage in your loop(starting at `for (Additional_Contact_Role__c cr : contactsFromQ_List2)`), there is only one thing you should do:

Make sure that there is at least 1 element in your list! If you try to iterate over an empty list, the code will immediately jump out of the loop ==> not testing what's inside the loop